# Java Spring file download

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@RequestMapping(value = "download", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String download(
        @RequestParam(value = "questionId") String question,
        HttpServletResponse response, HttpServletRequest request) {

    QuestionDto questionDto = null;

    try {
        Integer questionIdentifier = Integer.parseInt(question);
        questionDto = this.userHelpAndSupportService.getQuestionById(questionIdentifier);
        String filename1 = questionDto.getAttachmentName();

        if (filename1.contains(".doc") || filename1.contains(".docx")) {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-word");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=" + filename1);
        } else if (filename1.contains(".xls")
                || filename1.contains(".xlsx")) {
            response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=" + filename1);

        } else if (filename1.contains(".pdf")) {
            response.setContentType("application/pdf");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=" + filename1);
        } else if (filename1.contains(".txt")) {
            response.setContentType("application/txt");
            response.setHeader("Content-Disposition",
                    "attachment;filename=" + filename1);
        }
        OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
        FileCopyUtils.copy(questionDto.getAttachment(), out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (questionDto != AdPlannerAdminConstants.NULL){
            PlatformLoggerUtil.info(this.getClass(),"The filename to be downloaded is "+questionDto.getAttachmentName());
            PlatformLoggerUtil.error(this.getClass(),"Exception in AdminHelpAndSupportController:download "+e);
        }


    }
    return null;
}
```

Whenever i try to download file, in mozilla and chrome the extension for the file is getting changed for some file . The downloaded file is not readable. How to fix this issue any idea?

Comment: _"the extension for the file is getting changed for some file "_ - changed from what to what? What does the file content look like?  Have you examined the interaction in your browser's debug console to see what is actually being received? You've omitted important details making it much harder for anyone to help you.

Comment: Side comments: (1) The mapping from file extension to content-type should be handled with a static `HashMap` that gets loaded from a properties file; (2) You should be smarter about parsing off the file extension. You'll get "interesting" results in your existing code with a filename like `a.xls.txt`.; (3) You need to set the content-disposition header in only one place as it's always the same regardless of the filetype.  If you implement item (1) this problem goes away on its own.